# Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with - T switch

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to check services in linux with the command `status`.
However I get this error:

> Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with - T switch at checkservices line 3.

In the line I have this:

```perl
my @services = `status\;
```

Whats the problem here?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my @services = `status`;
foreach my $service(@services){
    if (! (service =~ /{running|UP} /)) {
        print "up";
    }  
}
```

Comment: Showing more code would be more helpful to you to get answer.

Comment: All the code is here now

Comment: Please make sure it compiles before you post your question. Use `use warnings;`. Capitalization matters. Variable names start with `$` or `@`. Legibly formatted code is easier on the eyes. Do you really have a `status` command?

Comment: Yes,  the command returns list of services,  and if they up or down

Comment: If you ever get a warning or error from Perl that you don't understand then it's worth adding `use diagnostics` to the program to you get more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [perlsec](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Cleaning-Up-Your-Path):

> For "Insecure $ENV{PATH} " messages, you need to set $ENV{'PATH'} to a known value, and each directory in the path must be absolute and non-writable by others than its owner and group. You may be surprised to get this message even if the pathname to your executable is fully qualified. This is not generated because you didn't supply a full path to the program; instead, it's generated because you never set your PATH environment variable, or you didn't set it to something that was safe. Because Perl can't guarantee that the executable in question isn't itself going to turn around and execute some other program that is dependent on your PATH, it makes sure you set the PATH.
>
> Perl does not call the shell to expand wild cards when you pass system and exec explicit parameter lists instead of strings with possible shell wildcards in them. Unfortunately, the open, glob, and backtick functions provide no such alternate calling convention, so more subterfuge will be required.

Comment: How do is set $env{path}?

Comment: By setting it `$ENV{PATH} =` (to some path appropriate for your system)

Comment: Can you give me an example,  it will relly help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1747796/4248931, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11069137/4248931

Comment: @ArielLivshits `print $ENV{PATH}` would be an example for the value `$ENV{PATH}` could have. Obviously.

Answer (score 2):

For those running into this error while trying to reset Postgresql follow these steps:

- sudo rm /var/lib/postgresql/[postgres version]/main/postmaster.pid
- sudo chown postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/[postgres version]/main/environment
- sudo chmod u+rw,g+rw /etc/postgresql/[postgres version]/main/environment

Got it from [this link](https://tjhia.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/postgresqlinsecure-directory-in-envpath-while-running-with-t-switch-at-usrbinpg_ctlcluster/).

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one! Thank you for coming back to share.