# su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Permission denied

Tags: bash, postgresql, ubuntu, permissions

I have installed the Postgres v-12 using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04) blog on my ubuntu 20.04. After installing that when I run the command

```
pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
```

I got the below error

> Insecure directory in $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at
> /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 398.

To fix this error I tried to give permission 750 to `/bin` directory as per the [blog](https://thedataguy.in/postgrsql-insecure-directory-in-env-path/) and followed the rest of the steps mentioned there. So when I run the command `su postgres` I gotthe below error

```
su: failed to execute /bin/bash: Permission denied
```

I have tried many blogs but didn't get any success.

Can anyone help me to run the Postgres?

Comment: Changing the permissions on `/bin` to 0750 will break your system. Change it back right away.

Comment: What repo did you install Postgres from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have installed the latest. using `apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`

Comment: Well this is a PERL problem[$ENV{PATH}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541262/insecure-envpath-while-running-with-t-switch). One that I have not seen on my Ubuntu installs. Have you tried `sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start`?